# Use of uninitialized value in list assignment in Perl

Tags: perl, local, initialization

When I run the code below, I get warning "Use of uninitialized value in list assignment":

```
local %ENV = ();
%ENV = foo(); //foo returns a hash
```

The dump result of %ENV is:

```
{
  'KEY1' => '-',
  'KEY2' => '-',
}
```

But the warning keeps coming out at line `%ENV = foo()`;

Thanks!

Comment: Add the code for `foo()`

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot Thanks for your advice. The foo() is pretty complicated, so I added the result of ENV instead. Please find it in the question update

Comment: @Terry maybe you add full code and also add `use strict; use warnings` in your script?

Comment: The problem very clearly lies in the code you're not posting.  Since `foo()` is complex, replace it with a dummy version that produces the same output.  For example `sub foo { return ('KEY1'=>'-','KEY2'=>'-'); }`.  Then post all of the code surrounding the error, including your dump statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:

It seems that there is special behavior when trying to assign an `undef` **value** to `%ENV`. If I do `$ENV{foo} = undef;` I get the warning you're seeing.

This makes sense when you consider that `%ENV` is mucking about with the environment. [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Environment-Access.html) has this to say for `setenv`: "A null pointer for the value parameter is illegal". If you want to delete an environment variable, delete it from the hash. If you want to set it to an empty string, use and empty string as a value. Using `undef` (which would be equivalent to `null`) doesn't make any sense here.

Check your `foo()` to make sure that none of the values it's returning are `undef`.

---

Old answer:

Are you sure that `foo()` is returning what you're trying to use in `%ENV`?

Here's an example that populates `%ENV` from `foo()`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

local %ENV = (); # redundant use of 'local' in example
%ENV = foo();
print Dumper(\%ENV);

sub foo {
        my %hash = ( "foo" => "bar" );
        return %hash;
}
```

Which outputs the expected:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'foo' => 'bar'
        };
```

It might be worth using the debugger to test what `foo()` returns and what's contained within `%ENV`.

Also, double check to make sure that your localized version of `%ENV` is still in scope when you try to use it. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

{
        local %ENV = ( "foo" => "bar" );
        print $ENV{foo}, "\n"; # expect "bar"
}
print $ENV{foo}, "\n"; # expect warning
```

Results in:

```
bar
Use of uninitialized value in print at ./test2.pl line 10.
```

Because the localized version of %ENV doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent demo. My `foo()` is returning what I want, and I have validated that using Dump. But the program is still complaining the warning.

Comment: Exactly which line is producing the error? It might be worth sharing a bit more of your code.

Comment: The line `%ENV = foo()` is producing the warning. The code is greatly simplified in the example for readability.

Comment: Updated my answer. Not sure if it's related to your scenario but it's the only way I can generate the same error.

Answer (score 4):

`foo()` is returning an `undef` in its results.  Initializing `local %ENV = ()` has nothing to do with the uninitialized value that `foo()` is returning.

Also, technical note: `foo` is not returning a hash.  It may be returning a list of values that you then assign to populate a hash, but a function can only return a scalar or a list, but not a hash.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have double checked that `foo` is not returning `undef` (please find that in the updated question).

Comment: @Terry : I suggest you dump `%ENV` and `%{foo()}` separately to see if there are any differences.